# Google calendar api - How to avoid double booking?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Is there a way to avoid race conditions when inserting events into Google Calendar using the API? I have an experimental app that needs to insert events into user's calendar. However, the user should not be double booked at a particular time.

The only true way of guaranteeing something like this is if Google provides a way. Other solutions are prone to race conditions (example, some other app that the user has updating it while my app is ignorant). The options as far as I can tell:

1. E-Tags with If-Match option - But this option is not valid for inserts according to the docs (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/version-resources).

> Important: There is no support for conditional modifications for
>   insert operations. Instead, it is guaranteed that if you are allowed
>   to provide a resource ID, then the operation will only succeed if no
>   existing entry has that ID.

So if I provide an if-match with the calendar etag and try to insert, it always fails regardless of the fact that the etag is correct.

2. Using "watch" for a brief period while the event is about to be inserted (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch). However, this solution is prone to race conditions due to the time take to get notified. One user inserting while my app gets notified of the update is problematic.
3. Sync the whole calendar with server periodically and consider the source of truth as the synced version and avoid double booking. Less optimal because new events added won't get synced fast enough, but the most likely will work.

What other solutions come to mind? I think #3 is the most suitable to guarantee consistency and integrity of data to avoid double booking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this on [this blog](https://robinpowered.com/blog/how-to-prevent-double-booking-events-in-google-calendar/) which states that you'll be using [Calendar Resource API](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/introducing-new-calendar-resource-api.html) instead of the Google Calendar. I think this guide is what you're looking for.

> Unlike a regular calendar, resources:
>
> -Do not allow conflicts
>
> -Can be shared across everyone on your Google Apps domain
>
> -Can be invited (multiple at a time) to events, just like a person
>
> -Their ability to share availability with everyone makes resources great for managing rooms schedules. Especially in a shared work
>   environment like your office.
>
> FYI: This guide assumes you already have Google Apps. Currently only
>   paid accounts have access to resource calendars. If you’re
>   grandfathered in or using a personal Gmail account, this process won’t
>   make much sense.

Comment: Thanks. However, it seems like its resource oriented..i.e. for conference rooms, meeting rooms etc. I was looking for setting up a meeting between two people not necessarily a resource